# Can you help me identify this poly bag #4 with many grey pieces?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

[image]

We got this bag in a free box and don't know what it is!

Answer (score 5):

I'll be happy to help out, my Friend. It comes from [*Set #75103 First Order Transporter*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75103-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).
See ya around Space Cowboy!

[image]

Comment: @aQui Welcome to Bricks! If this has answered your question, you can click the tick mark and the upvote arrow to the left of the answer to let others know that this was helpful and answered :)